# How to highlight marker on leaflet map with data match on table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, tabulator

I have some data like Place name , latitude longitude which is showing in table and when i click any row it gets the place name and show highlighted marker on leaflet map according to this. But when i click another row it is also highlighted marker on map but previous one is still highlighted. i want to highlight new one not previous one.

I have call a function when i click row on table and create marker.

```
rowClick:function(e, row){
   var cells = row.getCells();
   var rid   = cells[0].getData().id;
   var Latt  = cells[1].getData().Latitude;
   var Lang  = cells[2].getData().Longitude;

   alert("cell clicked - (" + Latt + ", " + Lang + ") " +rid);
   var marker = new L.marker([Latt, Lang]).addTo(mymap);
   marker.valueOf()._icon.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
   marker.bindPopup('' + rid).openPopup();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you don't want to use `bindPopup` because, as you noticed, it's reusing a single popup.

Use your own popup ...

```
map.closePopup(myPopup); // close previous

myPopup =  L.popup(...);        
myPopup.setContent(...);
myPopup.setLatLng(...);
myPopup.openOn(map);
```

When you have a list of places aside your map, you may want to add a few event listeners: e.g. what happened if you click on a marker after clicking on an item of your list ?

You will also want to keep a relationship between your markers and the items of your tables.

A full blown example here: http://franceimage.github.io/map (the table is shown when you click on the 3rd icon in the left toolbar)